# How can I get current window login username and password in php?

Tags: php

I tested this coding in xampp server and username is true.

```
<?php 
    echo getenv("username"); 
?>
```

But I logged in with different username, it shown the first username.
How can I get current window login username in php?

Comment: Why are you taking the username from the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Do you execute your php script via CLI? If so i would simply use

```
<?php
exec('whoami', $whoami);
return trim($whoami[0]);
?>
```

But as already stated by others you cant retrieve a password for any logged in system user

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the username and password of a user except to ask for it.

The environment variable will only give you the username under wich the Script is running. If you call it through a webserver, it will be the username under which the webserver runs. If you run the script from a shell you'll get the username under wich you ran the script. There is no way to get the password from an environment variable (which is good, that would be a huge security hole).

If you want to get the username and password from the user who visits your website you'll have to get this information through other means. You didn't provide details on the operating system you use, so this can only be answered generally.

Using Windows (on the client side) you can get the username through [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager), but this will still not provide you with the password of the user, it uses a different authentication method like Kerberos. And as said, being a Microsoft solution it is only available with Windows clients and isn't supported with all browsers.

To get username and password you will have to ask the user for both, either with a form on your website or with authentication through the webserver.